# Can't create connection between objects in Talend

Tags: talend

I'm new in Talend.

I've created two simple objects - an input CSV from Metadata -> File delimited,
and a tLogRow from Log & Errors.

Now I'm trying to drag&drop the input CSV to tLogRow in order to create an arrow between them.

However, no arrow is created.

I've tried all possible combinations of mouse buttons and ALT/SHIFT/CTRL keys.

Anyone knows what's I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First drag and drop the components in your job designer :

- Dnd the csv metadata from your repository to your job. Select tFileInputDelimited as component type
- Dnd the tLogRow from the palette to your job

Right-click on the tFileInputDelimited and select row -> main.
Then click on the tLogRow component to create the dataflow

Answer (score 0):

You can hold right click of mouse and point any component it should connected by "Main".